# How can I access native HTML attributes in stenciljs? And how to make it appear in the documentation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, stenciljs

The web components made with stenciljs don't extend HTMLElement. How can I access the native attributes and use them in my component, say the `title` attribute? When I add `@Prop() title` and use it in my template an error is shown.

Adding `@Prop()` also makes the attributes visible in the generated documentation. How can I add the used or required native attributes to the generated documentation?

Compiler error I'm getting:

```
The @Prop() name "title" is a reserved public name. Please rename the "title" prop so it does not conflict
with an existing standardized prototype member. Reusing prop names that are already defined on the element's
prototype may cause unexpected runtime errors or user-interface issues on various browsers, so it's best to
avoid them entirely.
```

Comment: which error will be shown when you try to compile?

Comment: Yes, you are not allowed to do so but you can pass them directly to the element via attributes or properties. You can pass your title directly without declaring it with the @Prop decorator. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to read the `title` attribute and use it in my component. The `title` attribtue sets a hover text on an element usually, so in addition to the hover effect, I want to read the value of `title` inside of my component and view it. I know I can add a `dataTitle` attribute, but then I have to set the `data-title` and `title` separately. In some cases that's a better approach, but in other cases it's redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are not allowed to do so but you can pass HTML attributes directly to the element without declaring them with the `@Prop` decorator. In your case, just pass `title` to your component.

```
<your-component title="test title"></your-component>
```

Then, if you would like to read the value of your title attribute, you have to get the reference to the host element first.

```
@Element() host: HTMLElement;
```

Then, you can read it with your host element's getAttribute method, for instance:

```
componentDidLoad() {
  const title = this.host.getAttribute('title');
  console.log(title); // or do something with it
}
```

Comment: Thats a good one! I used that before but forgot it completly... One thing to mention here is that this will only read once from the title tag at the end of the lifecycle of the component. So there is no two way binding and maybe you have to use more or different hooks. But of course that depends on the application

Answer (score 2):

`@Prop()` is like reading from **tag to component**

`@Prop({"reflectToAttr": true})` will keep a two way binding and updates both - **tag to component & component to tag**

It's important to know that you are **not allowed to update** your `@Prop` variables inside the component until you specifically allow it with the mutable property. `@Prop({"mutable": true})`

If you want both just use comma seperated syntax like:

```
@Prop({"mutable": true, "reflectToAttr": true})
```

For details please go here:
https://stenciljs.com/docs/properties

I faced sometimes some issues using the native attributes like `"title", "focus"` and so on. The correct way would be using `"data"` before the attribute like `"data-title", "data-focus"` and in the component `@Prop() dataTitle`, `@Prop() dataFocus`.

But to be honest i don't like that the developer using the web-components have to learn a web-component specific syntax so i use the native attributes anyway. Which results sometimes in some errors that you can fix easily. But this would be a topic for another question.

> @Update

I just realized that in newer StencilJS versions is just `@Prop({"reflect": true})` but the idea is still the same

Comment: The error I'm getting is `the @Prop "title" is a reserved public name`. I added the full error to the OP. The thing is that I want to use the native attributes, and I also think the error handling is what I actually need. I believe using @Prop "title" works as intended on Chrome, but the error message causes some concern for future compatibility or future problems with other browsers or on mobile devices.